# How to find video downloaded from YouTube?

Tags: video, downloads

I have a Nokia Lumia 1320 and I'm using some apps to download videos from YouTube. The apps work well but the problem is, the videos I download don't appear in videos list. They only appear in the app that I downloaded them with. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Apps in Windows Phone / Mobile are sandboxed, meaning that they each save their content to their own little space unless told by the developer to do otherwise. If you want to access the videos outside of the app you'll have to download an app that allows you to save to your videos library. If you're using Windows 10 Mobile, [MyTube!](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/mytube/9wzdncrcwf3l) works well (it may also work in WP8(.1); I don't have a phone to test.)

**Update** : It works on WP8.1 too.

Answer (score 2):

The best app to download YouTube videos in Windows phone would be the UC browser.

1. Go to the video you want to download.
2. Click on the video icon located at the bottom left corner.
   [image: YouTube video in UC browser]
3. You will get a popup windows as shown below.
   [image: Saving YouTube video offline]
4. Tick the save to SD card option and click the watch offline button.
5. You will have the video downloaded in to the UC downloads folder in
   the SD card.

Most other apps allow the videos to be accessed only within that app.

Comment: Gotta disagree here. There are multiple apps with better designs and data saving (MyTube and Metrotube come immediately to mind.)

Comment: I don't think those apps allow saving the video to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

The app uses its own directory, If You want to get the files to Videos. Download a File Manager and move the files there.

Comment: Since most of the applications directory are Sandboxed they cannot be accessed using a Filemanager.